# Detached DOM tree is referenced as the native link

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get rid of detached DOM Elements and having a hard time finding the cause of the leak.

Can somebody help me understand what  *native link from DOM wrapper stored in the detached window property* is. What does it mean **native link**?

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks

> By tracing paths to window objects, it can be observed, that the
>   detached DOM tree is referenced as the native link from the DOM
>   wrapper stored in the detached window property. To confirm this, do
>   the following...

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have linked, there is a variable called 'detached' that is being created as a global on the window object.

window.detached

They then go on to generate an entire DOM tree with lots of children and extra data and they store that reference in the window.detached variable. It is not however actually mounted into the DOM.

The block that you have quoted is just pointing out that if you have any dom nodes you've generated that still have an active reference pointing to them (in this case the reference is window.detached) then they will not be garbage collected.

They go to the trouble of pointing this out because some people may expect that as soon as you unmount a tree of nodes from the DOM that they are candidates for GC. They're pointing out that what really matters is if there is still a reachable reference to the item. If not, it will be GC'ed. Otherwise it will hang around.